# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[imageKey].urls'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Tried to rewrite a class component in functional, using hooks. I rewrote the method but knocks out the error that I do not transmit data, I do not understand exactly how to transfer. The error says

> undefined is not an object (evaluating `data[imageKey].urls`).

I pass  `imgsource={{ url: modalImage }}` to render the picture but an error appears

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    Dimensions,
    Modal,
    ScrollView,
    ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

import ImageElement from './ImageElement'

const ImageListWithHooks = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=cf49c08b444ff4cb9e4d126b7e9f7513ba1ee58de7906e4360afc1a33d1bf4c0')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState()
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)
    const [modalImage, setModalImage] = useState(props.imgsource)

     const setModal = ((visible, imageKey) => {
        setModalImage({ modalImage: visible ? data[imageKey].urls.raw : null })
        setModalVisible({ modalVisible: visible })
    })

    let images = data.map((val, key) => {

        return <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={key}
            onPress={() => { setModal(key) }}>
            <View style={styles.imagewrap}>
                <ImageElement
                    author={{ url: val.user.profile_image.small }} // фото автора
                    imgsource={{ url: val.urls.small }} // работа автора
                    authorNameProp={val.user.name}   // имя автора
                ></ImageElement>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    });
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal
                    style={styles.modal}
                    animationType={'fade'}
                    transparent={true}
                    visible={modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => { }}
                >
                    <View style={styles.modal}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}
                            onPress={() => { setModal(true) }}>Close</Text>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.spinner}>Loading... <ActivityIndicator /></Text>
                        </View>
                        <ImageElement
                            imgsource={{ url: modalImage }}
                        ></ImageElement>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
                {images}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did I help you recently with some code that looked very similar to this? You've a bug in `onPress={() => { setModal(key) }}` where you pass `key` to the `visible` argument and `imageKey` is undefined in your `setModal` callback. I think I recall a similar issue in previous code. `data[undefined]` yields `undefined` and you can't access an `urls` property.

Comment: So a similar error was when in the previous code when I was writing the class component. So far I do not understand how to correct this error.

Comment: I checked your response data and all elements in the array appeared to have an `urls.raw` property. Did you try addressing the issue I pointed out above? You should consistently pass a `visible` ***and*** `imageKey` arguments to `setModal`.

Comment: So I try to solve a problem which when calling setModal will open a modal window. 
I don't quite understand how I have to convey arguments consistently.

Comment: You've a button around your image element that passes only a `key` (`onPress={() => { setModal(key) }}`), and another button in the modal that passes only a boolean `visible` (`onPress={() => { setModal(true) }}`. You've defined `setModal` to consume a `visible` and `imageKey` arguments. If you can describe again what you want the desired behavior to be when a user interacts with these two buttons I can suggest a more targeted solution. If I had to guess, you want the modal to be open/visible when the image is pressed, and closed/un-visible when the modal's close button is pressed, yeah?

Comment: So. The first button activates the modal window when you click on the image, ie opens the image to full screen. The second button closes this window after clicking the "close" button, or when you click anywhere, the window closes.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

- In `setModal` handler `imageKey` is undefined
- When `imageKey` is undefined then `data[imageKey]` resolves to `data['undefined']` which itself is undefined
- You can't access properties of an undefined object/value

You've defined a `setModal` handler to consume two arguments, `visible` and `imageKey`

```
const setModal = ((visible, imageKey) => {
  setModalImage({ modalImage: visible ? data[imageKey].urls.raw : null });
  setModalVisible({ modalVisible: visible });
});
```

but inconsistently pass arguments to it. You create an array of buttons to open a modal and pass the image key to the `visible` argument, which is really the array index. Index `0` is falsey, and all non-zero indices are truthy.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  key={key}
  onPress={() => { setModal(key) }} // <-- pass only 
>
  ...
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

`setModal` never receives a valid image key so `data[imageKey]` is undefined and you can't access the `urls` property of the undefined value since it isn't an object.

You also pass the wrong boolean value to the handler in the "close" button within the modal.

```
<Modal
  ...
  visible={modalVisible}
  ...
>
  ...
  <Text
    style={styles.text}
    onPress={() => { setModal(true) }} // <-- true sets modalVisible true
  >
    Close
  </Text>
  ...
```

## Solution

When you want to open the modal pass `true` for the `visible` argument, and `key` for the `imageKey` argument.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  key={key}
  onPress={() => setModal(true, key)} // <-- pass true and index key 
>
  ...
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

When you want to close the modal pass `false` for the `visible` argument. Here the key is irrelevant since you aren't accessing anything with it in the handler and setting modal image state back to `null`.

```
<Modal
  ...
  visible={modalVisible}
  ...
>
  ...
  <Text
    style={styles.text}
    onPress={() => setModal(false)} // <-- false sets modalVisible false
  >
    Close
  </Text>
  ...
```

Comment: You explain very clearly. I seem to have fixed the error, but calling onPress doesn't work when I want to create a modal window. Here I tried to apply to cancel const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState (false). But it does not work properly. But when const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState () opens a modal window but does not load the image data [imageKey] .urls.raw.Do not render the picture. hmm